# 2d-mini element-can't use sub(0),but bubble element is ok

Tags: python, fenics

My program (in Python, using FEniCS):

```
mesh=UnitSquareMesh(16,16)
U_h = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "Lagrange", 1)
B = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "Bubble", degree=3,dim=2)
Mini_h = U_h + B
```

Boundary definition (for example, `u0_boundary` and `u1_boundary` are part of square, respectively):

```
w0 = Constant("0.0")
bc0 = DirichletBC(Mini_h.sub(0), w0, u0_boundary) #error
bc1 = DirichletBC(Mini_h.sub(1), w0, u1_boundary)
```

I get: `ValueError: Can only extract SubSpaces with i = 0 ... -1`

Who can tell me why? `Mini_h.sub(0)` is the first component of `Mini_h`.

Actually, the problem is only for vector bubble element, everything is OK. For example:

```
B = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "Bubble", degree=3,dim=2)
bc0 = DirichletBC(B.sub(0), w0, u0_boundary)
bc1 = DirichletBC(B.sub(1), w0, u1_boundary)
```

In addition, I want to know why can not directly added to a mini finite element, rather than CG + Bubble.

Comment: `Mini_h.num_sub_spaces()` returns `0` for your example, so the problem is probably in the construction of `Mini_h`.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the Mini element in this alternative manner if you want a mixed enriched element rather than an enriched mixed element:

```
U = FunctionSpace(mesh, "Lagrange", 1)
B = FunctionSpace(mesh, "Bubble", 3)
M = U + B
Mini_h = MixedFunctionSpace([M, M])
```

Answer (score 2):

The vector part of the MINI element is not a mixed function space, which is why you cannot extract a subspace from it. The bubble is an enrichment (which is indicated by the '`+`' in your construction of `Mini_h`.

The distinction between mixed and enriched spaces is discussed in Section 2.3 of the UFL paper:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4047

Comment: Yes, but consider that one would appreciate associativity of `*` and `+` operation so that `Mini_h.sub(0) == U_h.sub(0) + B.sub(0)`. Is there major design issue why it is not possible?

Comment: Yes,you are right.

    U = FunctionSpace(mesh, "Lagrange", 1)
    B = FunctionSpace(mesh, "Bubble", 3)
    Q = FunctionSpace(mesh, "DG", 1)
    M = (U + B)*(U + B)
    Mixed_h = MixedFunctionSpace([M,Q])

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- enforce Dirichlet condition for all components `DirichletBC(Mini_h, u_D, domain)` where `u_D` is some `Function`, `Expression` or `Constant` of appropriate dimension, or
- use coordinate-free approach, for example [FEniCS: separate boundary conditions in normal and tangential direction of mesh boundary](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/7123/4254), but I'm not sure if it can be succesfully implemented in FEniCS.

Answer (score 0):

This problem have be solved,thanks everyone!

```
U = FunctionSpace(mesh, "Lagrange", 1)
B = FunctionSpace(mesh, "Bubble", 3)
Q = FunctionSpace(mesh, "DG", 1)
M = (U + B)*(U + B)
Mixed_h = MixedFunctionSpace([M,Q])
```

This time we can use Mixed_h.sub(0).sub(0).